# Get Fetch Response Status Without Performing A Fetch

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

Is there a way to use `Fetch()` or `XMLHttpRequest()` to get the response's status: `if(response.status == 200)` or to see if the response is 'ok': `if(response.ok)` without actually fetching the entire page. This has to be in JavaScript, and I am trying to make the response as quick as possible. I am making a page that downloads videos from another website. I would prefer to not use the cross-origin proxy if possible, but it is what it is.
**Here Is My Code:**

```js
var links = ['https://example.com/video1.mp4','https://example.com/video2.mp4','https://example.com/video3.mp4']
links.forEach(function(item, index) {
    var requestplace = new Request('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + item);
    fetch(requestplace).then(function(response) {
        if(response.ok) {
            console.log(`Link #${index + 1}: ${item}`);
        }
        else {
            console.log(`Link #${index + 1}: FAILED`)
        }
});
```

Comment: use request `method: "HEAD"`? ... i.e. `fetch(requestplace, { method: 'HEAD'})` (actually, no, put that in the `new Request(...., {method: 'HEAD'}`

Comment: @JaromandaX If I had the reputation to upvote I would. That really helps. I appreciate it. If you want to make that into an answer, I will mark it as 'the best answer'. Now the video links are retrieved in seconds. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to check the existence of a resource, use the `HEAD` http method

var links = ['https://example.com/video1.mp4','https://example.com/video2.mp4','https://example.com/video3.mp4']

```
links.forEach(function(item, index) {
    var requestplace = new Request('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + item, {
       method: 'HEAD'
    });
    fetch(requestplace).then(function(response) {
        if(response.ok) {
            console.log(`Link #${index + 1}: ${item}`);
        }
        else {
            console.log(`Link #${index + 1}: FAILED`)
        }
});
```